# Can I specify to JdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper to map a table column to a class field having a different name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a *Spring Boot* project using `JdbcTemplate` to access data and I have the following problem with a single specific field using `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to map the result of a query on a DTO object.

This is my repository method performing my query and mapping the query result on a DTO object:

```
@Override
public OneRowReadTrain1DTO getOneRowReadTrain1DTO() {
    
    String SELECT_SINGLE_RECORD_OneRowReadTrain1 = "SELECT * FROM OneRowReadTrain1";

    List<OneRowReadTrain1DTO> resultList = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_SINGLE_RECORD_OneRowReadTrain1, 
                                             BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(OneRowReadTrain1DTO.class));
    
    OneRowReadTrain1DTO result = resultList.get(0);
    
    return result;
}
```

It works fine except a specific field. The problem is that this field is the only one that doesn't have the same name as DTO class field and column name on my table.

Infact on my `OneRowReadTrain1DTO` I have:

```
public class OneRowReadTrain1DTO {
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE)
    private Date timeStamp;
    
    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
}
```

As you can see this class field is named as `timeStamp` but the related column on my table is `Time_Stamp` so this field is valorized as `null`.

There is a way to avoid to write a custom row mapper (the class fields\table columns are hundreds) and to specify that my `Time_Stamp` have to be mapped on the `timeStamp`?

I know that I can simply rename this field name in my class but it is pretty ugly.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? I would kind of that this works as a mapping for `time_stamp` should also be created in the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`. Else the best way is to write an explicit query with column aliases (which is also what is mentioned in the documentation of said class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "select *" you can select each field required for the DTO and give it the proper name of the field.

e.g.:   "select Time_Stamp as timeStamp, etc... "